# Specific variance covariance structure in lmer

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model, covariance-matrix

I have a dataset with cluster correlated data; multiple measurement on the same subject (not over time). I am trying to create two different mixed models using lmer in R with two specific variance covariance structures.  I am fairly confident I have my first model correct, I want each subject to have its own intercept but share a covariance parameter.  The second model I would like to allow for each subject to have its own covariance parameter.

model 1:

```
y ~ (1|subject)
```

$$
\Sigma = \sigma^2 \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
\Sigma_1 & 0 & \dots & 0  \\
0 & \Sigma_1 & & 0 \\
\vdots &  & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & \Sigma_1 
\end{array} \right)
$$

where:

$$
\Sigma_1 = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \sigma_1 & \sigma_1 \\
\sigma_1 & 1 & \sigma_1 \\
\sigma_1 & \sigma_1 & 1 
\end{array} \right)
$$

model 2:

This is where I have trouble.  I cant seem to find a way to allow a separate covariance estimate for each group.

$$
\Sigma = \sigma^2 \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
\Sigma_1 & 0 & \dots & 0  \\
0 & \Sigma_2 & & 0 \\
\vdots &  & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & \Sigma_n 
\end{array} \right)
$$

where:

$$
\Sigma_i = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \sigma_i & \sigma_i \\
\sigma_i & 1 & \sigma_i \\
\sigma_i & \sigma_i & 1 
\end{array} \right)
$$

Comment: I didnt realize this would be so difficult.  I recently read somewhere that lmer cannot do this type of heterogeneity and that I might need to use the nlme package instead. Can anyone confirm this?